# SAS procedure to create new columns based on variable values

Tags: sas

I need to make a TOP 10 table with month by month history like:

[image]

The problem is I have only "melted" data:

[image]

Is there a SAS procedure to create new columns in a dataset based on a variable values like in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PROC TRANSPOSE`

```
proc sort data=have;
    by type descending date;
run;

proc transpose data=have 
               out=want(drop=_NAME_)
               ;
    by type;
    id date;
    var total;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution suits me best, because it creates a dataset, that I can edit later.

Answer (score 0):

Your "melted" data is in a categorical form that is lock and load ready for a Proc TABULATE report.

Example:

```
data have;
input date yymmdd10. treatment: $10. count:;
format date yymmdd10.;
datalines;
2020-01-31 lolipops       5
2020-01-31 chocolate      4
2020-01-31 cakes          3
2020-01-31 cookies        2
2019-01-31 lolipops       2
2019-01-31 chocolate      3
2019-01-31 cakes          4
2019-01-31 cookies        5
2018-01-31 lolipops       3
2018-01-31 chocolate      4
2018-01-31 cakes          5
2018-01-31 cookies        6
;

ods html file='top10.html' style=plateau;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class date / descending;
  class treatment / order=freq;
  var count;
  table treatment='', date='' * count='' * sum='' * f=6.
  / box='Treat'
  ;
run;

ods html close;
```

Report

[image]

Comment: Melted data - maybe Carlito had dessert on his mind. What should we call a wide dataset? Chocolate Bar format? Waffle format?